# Android Studio CPU Usage is 100% even though i'm just coding and running the app on a physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, cpu, cpu-usage, amd-processor

When I open my task manager, I can see that my CPU Usage is getting high whenever I use Android Studio. I'm running my app on a physical device but the high usage still persists. If I start even just coding on Android Studio the CPU Usage spikes up to 99% and so on. I am using Amd Ryzen 3, with 8gb of RAM.How do I fix this? I hope you can help me!

Comment: [File a bug](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs) (although the answer from Ravi Kumar is a good idea too)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Android Studio, Navigate to Help > Diagnostic Tools > Activity Monitor to see what all process are consuming the CPU.

[image: Android Activity Monitor]

You can also turn on "Power Save Mode" , go to File > Power Save Mode to turn it on.